# PHPStorm Intermittently Prompting "File Cache Conflict" Dialog on Save

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Using v2.1.5. About half the time I save I get the dialog below.

Two questions:

1. Why does this happen intermittently? Maybe because I'm using CVS and my local storage is in another drive?
2. Is there a setting where I can default to "Keep Memory Changes" so that this dialog doesn't show up anymore?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now using version 3.0 and don't have this issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It can happen if file time stamp changes externally or when you store files not on a local drive.

Comment: Thanks on Q1. Any thoughts on Q2?

Comment: There is no such setting, but you can try to delete `fsnotifier.exe` from `PhpStorm\bin` directory, it will switch to java polling methods and should be able to detect changes on remote drives.

Comment: Sorry @CrazyCoder, but what do you mean by "java polling methods" and "should be able to detect changes on remote drives"? Does this mean I won't get those notifications anymore but PHPStorm will still try and make sure i have the latest file version?

Comment: Yes, in theory you get these notifications because PhpStorm is not aware of external changes until you want to save the file, and it happens because native fsnotifier doesn't support remote drives. I might be wrong, but you can easily test it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will give it a try tomorrow morning.

Comment: It seems that I'm still having this issue even after removing `fsnotifier.exe`. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Move files to the local disk.